# I'm making a Discord bot and auto-moderator for "bad words" doesn't work

Tags: python, discord.py

I made an auto moderator with a tutorial on YT and it doesn't work...I watched the tutorial corrected my mistakes and it still don't works can you helP?

````
@client.event
async def check_curses(message):
    if any([curse in message.content.lower() for curse in CURSES]):
          await message.delete()
          await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}, nie używaj tutaj takiego słownictwa!")
          return True
        return False```

I don't know what to do!
````

Comment: please check the indentation, it seems to be off. and you should also pass `CURSES` to the function.

Comment: Can we see the full code?  How are you calling this coroutine?  Are you seeing any error messages?

Comment: Your code raies `IndentationError` on line 6

Comment: Please note that "it doesn't work" is always incorrect: the code is doing _exactly_ what you told it to do, and is doing exactly what it should be doing. Your code isn't doing _what you expected_ so always describe things in terms of what  you wanted to do, what you see happening instead, and what part of that mismatch you can't figure out. Also, for whitespace-sensitive code like Python, _always make sure the code in your post is exactly as it is in your source file_ because as shown, your code can't even run. Python will throw an indentation error.

Comment: i'm not seeing any errors, but when i write for ex. "example1" it doesn't delete it and doesn't respond. I'm gonna edit and you'll see the full code

Comment: Please remember to not show "all the code". When asked for "the full code" what is really requested is a [mcve].

Comment: ok i'm not a proffesional don't criticise

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to get you started. This monitors all messages with `on_message()`

Also, don't forget that you'll need to properly set the permissions in a role for the bot. Also, just printing to the console when a curse is found.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    curse_words = ['badword1', 'badword2']
    if any(x in message.content.lower() for x in curse_words):
        print(f'Curse found')
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}, nie używaj tutaj takiego słownictwa!")
```

Results:

[image]